# Print lines between two patterns and ignore the lines if certain text found

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a file with 500+ lines. This file consists output of 3 server details separated by "---------" symbol with 5 categories.

For ex: I have a file named Test.txt in my Linux server

Contents of the file as follows.

```
########  
Server 1  
########  
--------  
Category 1  
No issue  
--------  
Category 2  
XYZ File system is 90%  
--------  
Category 3  
ABC codes are deployed  
--------  
Category 4  
No issue  
--------  
Category 5  
AB123 user is added  
--------  
########  
Server 2  
########  
--------  
Category 1  
Backup is completed  
--------  
Category 2  
XYZ File system is 90%  
--------  
Category 3  
ABC codes are deployed  
--------  
Category 4  
No issue  
--------  
Category 5  
AB123 user is added  
DD444 user is deleted
--------  
########  
Server 3  
########  
--------  
Category 1  
No issue
--------  
Category 2  
XYZ File system is 90%  
ABC File system is 95%  
--------  
Category 3  
ABC codes are deployed  
DEF codes are deployed  
--------  
Category 4  
No issue  
--------  
Category 5  
AB123 user is added  
CD456 user is added  
EF789 user is added  
AD111 user is added  
BB222 user is deleted
--------
```

Here i expect the output to be copied into new file by ignoring the No issue categories.

Expected output:

```
########  
Server 1  
########  
--------  
Category 2  
XYZ File system is 90%  
--------  
Category 3  
ABC codes are deployed  
--------  
Category 5  
AB123 user is added  
--------  
########  
Server 2  
########  
--------  
Category 1  
Backup is completed  
--------  
Category 2  
XYZ File system is 90%  
--------  
Category 3  
ABC codes are deployed  
--------  
Category 5  
AB123 user is added  
DD444 user is deleted
--------  
########  
Server 3  
########  
--------  
Category 2  
XYZ File system is 90%  
ABC File system is 95%  
--------  
Category 3  
ABC codes are deployed  
DEF codes are deployed  
--------  
Category 5  
AB123 user is added  
CD456 user is added  
EF789 user is added  
AD111 user is added  
BB222 user is deleted
--------
```

Since i am new to Unix scripting, i can barely achieve the output.

i tried below sed and awk commands but i did not succeed.
sed -n '/^------/,/^------/p, Test.txt -> But the output is missing some categories between "------" symbol

awk -v RS="------" '$0~/No/{​​​​​​​print $0 RS}​​​​​​​' Test.txt -> Getting symbol error

Can someone please help me achieve the desired output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO and good that you have shown your efforts in form of code, please do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS to make it more clearer.

Comment: Get rid of the `.` lines and anything else that's not REALLY part of your data (w.g. `till Server 3` I suspect isn't really in your input) so you provide something we can test a potential solution against.

Comment: When I run the awk command at the bottom of your question I get `awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ invalid char '▒' in expression` with the carat pointing at the `p` in `print`. Seems like you have some odd character in there. When I open it in an editor I see it's actually `awk -v RS="------" '$0~/No/{<200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b>print $0 RS}<200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b>' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="--------\n"} !/No issue/' file
########
Server 1
########
--------
Category 2
XYZ File system is 90%
--------
Category 3
ABC codes are deployed
--------
Category 5
AB123 user is added
--------
########
Server 2
########
--------
Category 1
Backup is completed
--------
```

The above was run against this input file (`.` and `till Server 3` lines removed from the end of the file and blanks removed from the end of lines compared to the file you posted in your question):

```
$ cat file
########
Server 1
########
--------
Category 1
No issue
--------
Category 2
XYZ File system is 90%
--------
Category 3
ABC codes are deployed
--------
Category 4
No issue
--------
Category 5
AB123 user is added
--------
########
Server 2
########
--------
Category 1
Backup is completed
--------
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Ed. I am getting error as "awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{RS=ORS="--------\n"} !/No/ file.txt" while trying to execute this command. I doubt if awk is working in my Linux OS. I got the same error while trying to execute simple awk commands. But i do get output while using sed commands. Can you help me with sed command format.

Comment: No, sed would be completely wrong for this task, it's just for doing `s/old/new` on individual strings. By far the most likely problem is you're simply doing something wrong when trying to execute an awk command - edit your question to show exactly what command you're trying to run and the exact error message you're getting so we can try to help you. And please do what I requested in [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64334471/print-lines-between-two-patterns-and-ignore-the-lines-if-certain-text-found/64337009?noredirect=1#comment113766483_64334471) too.

Comment: Ed, I have rephrased the actual question by removing "." with meaningful contents. FYI, all 5 categories are repeated on all 3 servers. And i wanted to pull only the contents with output by excluding "No issue" categories. I am providing output of awk command executed in my linux terminal. 
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="--------\n"} !/No crash/' File
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{RS=ORS="--------\n"} !/No crash/
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ invalid char '▒' in expression
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{RS=ORS="--------\n"} !/No crash/
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error
$ grep "No crash" Test
 No crash

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^----/{N;N;/No issue/d}' file
```

If the line beginning with dashes is matched, append the 2 following lines and if those lines contain the words `No issues` delete them.

An alternative, for variable lines between dashes:

```
sed '/^---/!{H;1h;d};x;/No issue/d;$G;1d' file
```

Comment: Better than my attempt `sed -z 's/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\nNo issue\n//g' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use grep -v

```
cat file.txt | grep -v "Category 1 No issue"
```

This will print the lines you want

Comment: I can only delete the lines which contains "No issues" words. However the header "Category 1,2,3,4,5" is still there with your suggested output. I would like to remove the line which contains "No issues" word along with its respective category from the server. i hope you can understand.